# In the proof of "A ring $R$ is commutative if and only if $[x,y]^3=[x,y]$ for all $x, y\in R$ where $[x,y]:=xy−yx$."

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The Theorem 17 from the paper [Variation on a Theme: Rings satisfying $x^3=x$ is commutative](http://archive.maths.nuim.ie/staff/sbuckley/Papers/bm_variations.pdf) by Stephen M. Buckley and Desmond MacHale says that "A ring $R$ is commutative if and only if $[x,y]^3=[x,y]$ for all $x, y\in R$ where [x,y]:=xy−yx."

Proof of this theorem in page 8 notes that "$e$ is a nonzero unity for $S$". I can't find any reason to this note. I tried to think of getting a contradiction if $e$ is zero, but it didn't work for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At this point in the proof, it is being assumed that $f$ and $g$ do not commute.  Since $f$ and $g$ are defined as multiples of $e$, if $e$ were $0$, then $f$ and $g$ would also be $0$ and so would commute.